# Maya keyframe animation to unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, maya

Sorry guys! I am super new to this, and I'm trying to teach myself Unity. I have a very small knowledge of Maya from a 3d modeling course I took a year ago in college, and have made a very simple object and animated it using keyframes (2 keyframes to be exact) in maya, but I can't seem to figure out how to get that animation into Unity.

I've been playing around with this for hours now, and all the tutorials and such I find online are for really complex objects like people, and they have joints and stuff going on. Are joints required for an animation to work in Unity?

I've saved my maya file into my assets folder, but I don't see any animations in the import settings in Unity.

**Here is my object:**

[image: img1]

**And it animates to this position:** 
[image: img2]

Comment: No, you do not need joints for non-humanoid objects. In the inspector, if you click on the original imported prefab, go to rig. Set the animation type to generic.

Comment: @Bobthezealot ive changed it to generic and an animation does show up but when I click play nothing actually moves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D why do we have maya and unity tags on this site if we can ask questions about them?

Comment: Because sometimes they're involved in a programming question, such as issues while writing a Maya importer or to discuss the Maya file format. Also, SO is a couple years old and certain rules have not been in effect all the time, ie there was a time when subjective, open-ended and rather pointless programming questions (What do you do when your code compiles?) were at least tolerated. So there are tags in the system that would no longer be considered useful today. Lastly, there are now more specialized sites for certain questions, like gamedev for instance but also code review and programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure but I think unity won't import animations from maya. Lights are not imported. I tested a comparable szenario a couple weeks ago with camera and motion path. But the animation was not imported.

Unity is a game engine and not a 3D-edit-programm.

Correct me when I'm wrong.